# Use the same session in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, session

I am trying to make repeated requests to the server. But each request is done with a different session ID. I've searched a lot but could not figure out how. I tried to set Keep-Alive in the request but it won't accept that header saying "unsafe header".

This is how I do

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", HOST, true);
request.send("test");
```

But each time I call send, the session ID is different at the server side. How can I make requests within the same session using JavaScript?

Comment: You can't, that has to be done at the server.

Comment: @Teemu Then what is the logic behind session handling? I am able to handle sessions on the server side but what is the point of it if every request comes with a different session ID regardless of browser or tab? I am able to do this in Java applications but I am quite new to HTML and Javascript. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: That depends on your server-side language.

Comment: @Teemu I am using Java Servlet. I've implemented the similar concept using Java. I am able to make requests within the same session repeatedly but in JavaScript, the XMLHttpRequest object is always closed when the response is received. I have to "open" the connection again which is probably creating a new session. I need to keep that object open even after the response is received. Is that possible?

Comment: @Teemu setting request.withCredentials = true helped me keep the same session for repeated requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that setting

```
request.withCredentials = true;
```

helped me keep the session.

Comment: I think you can also directly set request.session