# Django log out view doesn't work (no network traffic)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, xmlhttprequest

I'm learning Django to build the back end for my website. I'm making an authentication app for the project. I'm testing it using a separate html file instead of template since I want to eventually connect it to my front end. The log in view works fine but the log out one doesn't. It prints to the server terminal what looks like a success message: `"POST /members/logout_user/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10` but it doesn't do anything in the browser. I checked my admin site and I'm still logged in

Views:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['POST'])
def login_user(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponse("Logged in")

    else:
        return HttpResponse("incorrect")

@api_view(['POST'])
def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponse("logged out")
```

My html client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/members/login_user/">
      User name: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /> <br />
      Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <button onclick="logout()">Log out</button>
    <script>
      function logout() {
        csrf_cookieValue = document.cookie
          .split(";")
          .find((row) => row.startsWith("csrftoken"))
          .split("=")[1];
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/members/logout_user/");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "csrf_cookieValue");
        xhr.send();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I expect it to log me out. I check my other link: ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/``` and I'm still logged in (just added that to my post)

Comment: Is that page open before you logged out? Do you refresh that page if so?

Comment: yes, so the login_user work. I logged in over my html page and when I refresh the admin site I was logged in as expected. But when I try to log out over the html page, the admin site was still logged in when I refreshed it.

Comment: I see your `action` is a complete url rather than relative. Do you use a separate frontend by any chance?

Comment: Yes as I mentioned in the post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use the same session in XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50948129/use-the-same-session-in-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: Note: You will also need to configure CORS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245650/discussion-between-imcoding-and-abdul-aziz-barkat).

Answer (score 0):

use instead of this

```
@api_view(['POST'])
```

to

```
@api_view(['GET'])
```

because you can't give any input for logout.
so, your code should be this

and second, you need to expire token that create when you logged in.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def logout_user(request):
    request.user.auth_token.delete()
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponse("logged out")
```

Comment: I think I'm using sessions authentication. Also for this line ```request.user.auth_token.delete()```  the view doesn't seem to know which user it is since there is no data in the request ```AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'auth_token'```